# Hide/Show Password in a JTextFIeld (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, passwords, jtextfield

So I've been working on a Password Strength Checker and the way it works is that the user enters some random text into a textfield and then instantaneous visual feedback (breakdown of points) is displayed. I've also added a checkbox, which on being selected, should hide the password i.e. replace all the chars with asterisks, while preserving the actual text input by the user. A document listener is being used to keep track of changes inside the textfield. (each char on entry gets analyzed and then scored)

So, my question is, how exactly do I mask the user input with asterisks preserving its original value?

Here's what the GUI looks like:

http://speedcap.net/sharing/screen.php?id=files/51/2f/512f9abb3f92a25add7c593e9d80e9e4.png

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> How exactly do I mask the user input with asterisks preserving its original value?

Use the `JPasswordField` which has nice function `jPasswordField.getPassword();` to get the password as `char[]` to work with.

- Use `jPasswordField1.setEchoChar('*')` to mask the password characters with `*`.
- If you wish to see the value you are inserting use `jPasswordField1.setEchoChar((char)0);` Setting a value of `0` indicates that you wish to see the text as it is typed, similar to the behavior of a standard `JTextField`.

**Tutorial and Reference:**

1. [How to use Password Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html)
2. [setEchoChar(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#setEchoChar%28char%29)

Comment: Set echo character to 0 to disable masking: `jPasswordField1.setEchoChar('\u0000')`.

Comment: @Sage, whenever I click on the hide checkBox, the textfield loses focus, and then I have to click on the textfield again for the changes to take place. I used to function requestFocus on it to regain focus, but it doesn't seem to work. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: @EnTHuSiAsTx94, please post another question with a short description, so that i and other experienced people from the community can help you with, it is also preferable to attach a short and simple working example which is able to produce your problem :)\

Answer (score 3):

Use Password Field Instead of using textfield

Answer (score 2):

ok thanks for tutorialnya,

and ex,

action chechbox / double click

```
private void lihatActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  

   if (lihat.isSelected()) {
      password.setEchoChar((char)0); //password = JPasswordField
   } else {
      password.setEchoChar('*');
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This really seems like a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it as follows:

```
if ( jPasswordField.getEchoChar() != '\u0000' ) {
    jPasswordField.setEchoChar('\u0000');
} else {
    jPasswordField.setEchoChar((Character) UIManager.get("PasswordField.echoChar"));
}
```

Comment: Assuming this is not a `JTextField` but a `JPasswordField`.